# Why does docker fail to CHMOD when mounting an NFS volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nfs

My NFS exports look like this:

```
/export/plex_transcode *(fsid=1,rw,all_squash,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,crossmnt)
/export/plex_database *(fsid=2,rw,all_squash,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,crossmnt)
/export/plex_media *(fsid=3,rw,all_squash,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,crossmnt)
```

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  plex:
    image: plexinc/pms-docker
    container_name: plex
    environment:
      - TZ="Canada/Atlantic"
      - PLEX_CLAIM="xxx"
      - ADVERTISE_IP="http://xxxx:32400/"
      - ALLOWED_NETWORKS="192.168.0.0/24,172.20.0.0/16"
    volumes:
      - plex_database:/config
      - plex_transcode:/transcode
      - plex_media:/data
    ports:
      - 32400:32400/tcp
      - 3005:3005/tcp
      - 8324:8324/tcp
      - 32469:32469/tcp
      - 1900:1900/udp
      - 32410:32410/udp
      - 32412:32412/udp
      - 32413:32413/udp
      - 32414:32414/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  plex_database:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=dckr1.local,rw"
      device: ":/export/plex_database"
  plex_transcode:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=dckr1.local,rw"
      device: ":/export/plex_transcode"
  plex_media:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=dckr1.local,rw"
      device: ":/export/plex_media"
```

to troubleshoot I can run this as root:

```
mount -t nfs4 dckr1.local:/export/plex_media /mnt
```

and chmod in the /mnt directory just fine.  It's left me kinda scratching my head.

The error produced reads:

> Creating plex ... [1A[2K Creating plex ... [31merror[0m [1B ERROR: for
> plex Cannot create container for service plex: failed to chmod on
> /var/lib/docker/volumes/plex_plex_database/_data: chmod
> /var/lib/docker/volumes/plex_plex_database/_data: operation not
> permitted ERROR: for plex Cannot create container for service plex:
> failed to chmod on /var/lib/docker/volumes/plex_plex_database/_data:
> chmod /var/lib/docker/volumes/plex_plex_database/_data: operation not
> permitted Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: "chmod in the /mnt directory just fine" can you chmod /mnt itself (not a file or subdirectory)?

Comment: My experience with NFS is any squashing breaks most container workflows.

Comment: I tried removing the squash and the same problem persists.

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: @BitShift Play around with rootsquash on the serverside.